# How to fix INTERNAL SERVER ERROR in Retrofit2 Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm creating an application in Android Studio that requires API calls, as such I included Retrofit in my dependencies since it has more active community than Volley.

My code:

```kotlin
val body = LoginInformation("ken1","test",false)
            val call = ApiClient.apiService.postLogin(body)
//            Log.i("CHECK_RESPONSE",call.request().toString())
            call.enqueue(object : Callback<AuthLogin> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuthLogin>, response: Response<AuthLogin>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.i("CHECK_RESPONSE","onSuccess: ${response.body()}")
                    } else {
                        Log.i("CHECK_RESPONSE","onFailure: ${response.raw()}")
                    }
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuthLogin>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.i("CHECK_RESPONSE", "onError: ${t.message}")
                }
            })
```

My ApiService:

```kotlin
@POST("api/login")
    fun postLogin(
        @Body loginInformation: LoginInformation
    ): Call<AuthLogin>
```

Here are my Data classes:

LoginInformation.kt

```kotlin
data class LoginInformation(
    val user: String,
    val pass: String,
    val registrationMode: Boolean
)
```

AuthLogin.kt

```kotlin
data class AuthLogin(
    val success: Boolean,
    val user_id: Int
)
```

All parameters are required as rawJson, since I have set my converter(GSON) it should automatically convert my data classes in to raw Json. I'm pretty sure I included all parameters. The endpoint works in postman but not in Android Studio (The rest of endpoint works perfectly).

[image]

Comment: what is the response you are getting? is onFailure called?

Comment: I have a guess, but I'm not certain if it will resolve your issue.I noticed that the relative path in your Kotlin code is "api/login," while in Postman, it's "api/login/." I suggest adding a "/" at the end of your path in the @POST annotation.